# Python While Loop with multiple conditions

Tags: python, while-loop

Can anyone help as to why my while loop isn't working?
It's forcing the user to select either 1, 2 or 3, and not letting them proceed, however regardless of whether you put in 1, 2 or 3, it always says that you've entered a different number, and so says "Please choose level 1, 2 or 3"

```
level = input("Enter your level by typing 1, 2 or 3\n")
int(level)

levelSelect = 1
while levelSelect == 1:
   if level != int(1) or level != 2 or level != 3:
      level = input("Please choose level 1, 2 or 3\n")
      int(level)
   else:
      print("You have selected level", level)
      levelSelect = 0
```

Comment: As another side note, `int(1)` is *always* able to be replaced by `1`.

Comment: ...Unless you've done something silly like rebind the name `int`.

Comment: You need to change your "or" to "and" in your if statement.  It will always fail because level can't be 1 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `int(level)` doesn't do what you think it does.  It creates an integer from a string and *returns* it.  It does not operate in place.  Because of this, when you get to your `if` statement, you're comparing a string to integers which is always unequal.

You probably want:

```
level = int(level)
```

---

As a side note, the condition could also be written using the `in` operator:

```
if level in (1,2,3):
   print("level is ...")
else:
   print("pick again!")
   #other code ...
```

Answer (score 1):

See mgilson's answer regarding assign level as an integer but your logic in deciding if the 'level' is legitimate is also wrong.

Change:

```
if level != int(1) or level != 2 or level != 3:
```

for:

```
if level not in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Why do you say that *logic* is wrong? -- The style isn't ideal, but I don't think I see a problem with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (props to with Inbar Rose)

```
def get_level():
    while True:
        level = int(input("Enter your level by typing 1, 2 or 3\n"))
            if level in [1, 2, 3]:
                return level
```

Comment: why not put the whole thing into the while loop? http://pastebin.com/ArVpMNwF : `def choose_level():
    while True:
        level = int(input("Enter your level by typing 1, 2 or 3\n"))
        if level in [1, 2, 3]:
            return level`

Answer (score 0):

mgilson has indicated the core problem here, however I will make a suggestion to improve your code.

```
while True:
    level = input('Enter level: ')
    if level not in ('1','2','3'):
        print('Try again!\n')
    else:
        print('You chose level ', level)
        break
```